# Kernel load module error during boot up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, 15.10

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 on a dell laptop. It works fine but recently I've been getting slow boot times (~1 minute). So I was looking around and when I read the `/var/log/boot.log` file, I see the following error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
```

With every other service (except tftpd) running perfectly. Here's the full output:

```
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[  OK  ] Started Check And Enable File System Quotas.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1...
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
         Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script.
[  OK  ] Found device ST500LM012_HN-M500MBB 8.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/sda8...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/sda8.
         Mounting /mnt/ubuntuspace...
[  OK  ] Found device ST500LM012_HN-M500MBB 7.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/431a5631-95f2-4d4f-8f81-42e5801b57aa...
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/431a5631-95f2-4d4f-8f81-42e5801b57aa.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Mounted /mnt/ubuntuspace.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting Set console keymap...
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Starting Wait for all "auto" /etc/network/interfaces to be up for network-online.target...
         Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
         Starting Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
[  OK  ] Started Wait for all "auto" /etc/network/interfaces to be up for network-online.target.
[  OK  ] Started Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
         Starting Nameserver information manager...
[  OK  ] Started Nameserver information manager.
[  OK  ] Started Set console keymap.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
         Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
         Starting Restore Sound Card State...
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Listening on PC/SC Smart Card Daemon Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down....
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Started Cgroup management daemon.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
         Starting VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Network Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started crash report submission daemon.
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling...
         Starting LSB: Start/stop sysstat's sadc...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
         Starting Bluetooth service...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...
         Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Started Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
         Starting OpenVPN service...
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting LSB: Start daemon at boot time...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
         Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.4-main...
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
         Starting LSB: Monitor for system resources and process activity...
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down..
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Start/stop sysstat's sadc.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[  OK  ] Started OpenVPN service.
[  OK  ] Started Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
         Starting Hostname Service...
         Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
         Starting LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...
         Starting vboxweb-service.service...
         Starting vboxballoonctrl-service.service...
         Starting vboxautostart-service.service...
[  OK  ] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters.
[  OK  ] Started vboxweb-service.service.
[  OK  ] Started vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
[  OK  ] Started vboxautostart-service.service.
[  OK  ] Started Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Monitor for system resources and process activity.
[  OK  ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
[  OK  ] Started Accounts Service.
[  OK  ] Started Modem Manager.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Start daemon at boot time.
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[  OK  ] Started WPA supplicant.
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[  OK  ] Started MySQL Community Server.
[  OK  ] Started PostgreSQL Cluster 9.4-main.
         Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
[  OK  ] Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC...
         Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
         Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
         Starting LSB: Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
         Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
         Starting ISC DHCP IPv4 server...
         Starting LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
         Starting LSB: backup and restore program...
         Starting LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon....
         Starting LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd)...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
[  OK  ] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
[  OK  ] Started ISC DHCP IPv4 server.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: backup and restore program.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: HPA's tftp server.
See 'systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon..
[  OK  ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
         Starting Light Display Manager...
```

Here's the output of `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` :

```
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-07-06 06:05:56 IST; 1h 13min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 1019 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1019 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 06 06:05:56 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Jul 06 06:05:56 hostname systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 06:05:56 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
Jul 06 06:05:56 hostname systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 06 06:05:56 hostname systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

what exactly is the error, does it affect my boot times and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

**What is "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules" ?**

Systemd reads the files in the directory `/etc/modules-load.d` for modules to load with this service. If modules specified in these files are not present in the `/lib/modules` directory for the kernel being booted, the error 'failed to start load kernel modules' appears. Here's the contents of the `/etc/modules-load.d` directory from `ls -lA`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Apr 20 17:01 cups-filters.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 12 10:39 modules.conf -> ../modules
```

**Capture the details from `journalctl`**

In my case, here's the relevant part of `journalctl`:

```
May 27 06:36:50 zanna-X205TA systemd-modules-load[176]: Failed to find module 'lp'
May 27 06:36:50 zanna-X205TA systemd-modules-load[176]: Failed to find module 'ppdev'
May 27 06:36:50 zanna-X205TA systemd-modules-load[176]: Failed to find module 'parport_pc'
```

If you do `journalctl | grep modules` you will see which ones failed to load

In my case, `/etc/modules` (pointed to by symlink) was empty but the `cups-filters.conf` file contained the references to the modules that were throwing errors:

```
# Parallel printer driver modules loading for cups
# LOAD_LP_MODULE was 'yes' in /etc/default/cups
lp
ppdev
parport_pc
```

**Making the message disappear**

My laptop doesn't even have any parallel ports, unsurprisingly, so I don't need those modules. In any case, they couldn't be loaded as they were not in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`

I commented out those three lines (putting `#` at the start of the line in front of the module name for each one) and the error message disappeared.

I didn't notice any difference in boot time though.

**TL;DR**

- check `journalctl` to see which modules are failing to load
- read the files in `/etc/modules-load.d` to look for references to those modules
- comment out the lines that specify those modules to make the error disappear (but please make a back-up copy before editing)
- reboot to see if this makes any difference to boot time