# Ubuntu-Mate fails to boot on Raspberry-Pi 3

Tags: boot, root, mate

I wanted to change my OS on my pi to Ubuntu-Mate, so I downloaded the image and put it on my SD card. I guess I somehow messed it up, because it fails to boot with the error `Failed to start load kernel modules`.

I already had a look on [Kernel load module error during boot up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795360/kernel-load-module-error-during-boot-up/795421#795421), because I guess that basically could solve my problem, but I have no writing acces to `cups-filters.conf`, even though I'm in the root. (I tried it with `sudo nano /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf`).

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: which image did you write to the SDcard?

Comment: This one: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/